# Raise on astype('int') when input contains float values instead of casting them

Tags: python, pandas, casting

Given a simple DataFrame that as an integer and a float in column A and two integers in column B:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 100, 'B': 200}, {'A': 20.5, 'B': 20}])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
       A    B
0  100.0  200
1   20.5   20
```

Since column A contains a float, its dtype is guessed as `float64` by pandas while column B's dtype is guessed as `int64`:

```
In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]:
A    float64
B      int64
dtype: object
```

Now, when I convert column A's dtype to `int`, I get the following result:

```
In [4]: df.A.astype('int')
Out[4]:
0    100
1     20
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

The float value from the column `20.5` is automatically truncated into an integer `20`. However, I would rather have it raising an exception when trying to convert a float into integer so I know that the column holds non-integer values.

Is there any way how to achieve this? A fast method that also works with millions of rows is preferred.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to raise an exception on receiving floating point data that isn't integral, but you can check to see if a floating point column is integral by checking that `np.mod(x, 1) == 0` everywhere. That should be quick, too.

Comment: as_type has casting rules, none of which seems to apply (you'd think it'd be casting='safe' http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html )